# How to make custom ClassLoader to be returned by LoadedClass.class.getClassLoader()?

Tags: java, classloader, urlclassloader, dynamic-class-loaders

I'd like to create a classloader that extends classpath by several third-party jars. Currently my code looks like this:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        ClassLoader originalClassLoader = Main.class.getClassLoader();
        URL[] jarUrls = ...;
        ClassLoader customClassLoader =  URLClassLoader.newInstance(jarUrls, originalClassLoader);
        Class classFromJar = customClassLoader.loadClass("class.from.Jar");

        originalClassLoader.equals(classFromJar.getClassLoader()); // true
        customClassLoader.equals(classFromJar.getClassLoader()); // false
        // I want classFromJar.getClassLoader() to return customClassLoader
    }
}
```

The problem is that even though the class loading using `ClassLoader#loadClass` works fine, method `#getClassLoader` of loaded classes returns original classloader instead of the custom one. Such state causes calls like `classFromJar.newInstance()` to throw `ClassNotFoundExeption` because `originalClassLoader` doesn't know about additional jars and so dependencies of `classFromJar` can't be loaded.

**How to make custom classloader to propagate itself to results of `Class#getClassLoader` for loaded classes?**

I'd like to achieve that purely in runtime, without customizing "java.class.path" system property or JVM `-Djava.system.class.loader` switch.

Comment: Hmm, intresting question! As far as i am aware, there is a static field in the class `ClassLoader` that is called `scl` and stands for _System Class Loader_ which you can modify and replace it by your own class loader. This is the class loader returned when you invoke `ClassLoader#getSystemClassLoader()`. In order to modify it you will have to use reflection as it is private. **Please note:** this field's name may change in future versions, or may have already changed compared to previous verions!
I hope that is what you where looking for!